# Can't guess how to get a Doctrine instance

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In a symfony projects, I'm trying to persist a line of an association table (profil_role) composed of two objects (profil and role).

First, I developed The create action in the `ProfilRoleController` of the second project this way:

```
/** @var Roles $role */
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('main_project');
 $role = $em->getRepository("MyBundle\Entity\Roles")->find($roleId);
 $profil = $em->getRepository("MyBundle\Entity\Profil")->find($profilId);
 $profilRole = new ProfilRoles();
 $profilRole->setRoleId($role->getId());
 $profilRole->setProfilId($profil->getId());
 $em->persist($profilRole);
 $em->flush();
```

This part of code, call then the post entity action present in the main project:

```
/**
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=Response::HTTP_CREATED)
 * @Rest\Post("/profil_roles")
 */
public function postEntityAction(ProfilRoles $profilRole)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($profilRole);
    $em->flush();
    return $profilRole;
}
```

When I try to execute my code i'm getting this king of error:

```
Execution failed for request: POST /api/profil_roles? HTTP/1.1 {"profil":{"id":"12"},"role":{"id":"3"}}: HTTPCode 500, body {"code":500,"message":"Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information."}
```

I've tried to use the `@ParamConverter` annotation, but I don't how to use it my case.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ParamConverter` either, but looking at the snippets, something like `@ParamConverter("profilRole", class="MyBundle:ProfilRoles")` should work - have you tried this?

Comment: I've tried this but the request is oddly formed

Comment: i was searching exctly for the same problem. BTW, you can avoid calling your entity to make the relation by using getReference: `$item = $em->getReference('MyProject\Model\Item', $itemId); $cart->addItem($item);`

Comment: Could you please also show us Roles, Profil and ProfilRoles entities?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function postEntityAction()  {
   $postData = $request->request->all();
   $profileRole = $postData['profile_role']
```

Instead of this:

```
public function postEntityAction(ProfilRoles $profilRole)
```

Comment: still having the same problem.

Comment: (Try to delelte cache) can you please update the question with more information? For example the controller declaration

Comment: update answer, you have post data, I don't know which is your key (profile_role) @KubiRoazhon

Answer (score 0):

@AlessandroMinoccheri I've tried to be inspired by your reply to do this and i'ts workin, i don't know if it's the correct way.

```
 /**
 * @param ProfilRoles $profilRole
 * @param Request $request
 * @return ProfilRoles
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=Response::HTTP_CREATED)
 * @Rest\Post("/profil_roles")
 */
public function postEntityAction(Request $request)
{
    $profilRole = new ProfilRoles();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $requete = $request->request->all();

    $profilRole->setProfilId($requete['profil']['id']);
    $profilRole->setRoleId($requete['role']['id']);

    $em->persist($profilRole);
    $em->flush();
    return $profilRole;
}
```